# How to cast from hex to int and char?

Tags: c++, io

Is there a way to convert/cast from hex to decimal and form hex to char?  For example if you have:

```
string hexFile = string(argv[1]);
ifstream ifile;
if(ifile)
  ifile.open(hexFile, ios::binary);
int i = ifile.get();  // I am getting hex form hexFile and want to 
char c = ifile.get(); // convert it to a decimal representation for int and char
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? And you should clarify what exactly you want to do. Because assume you have a hex value 0x1a5f -> the corresponding decimal value 1a5f doesn't even exist. What kind of output do you expect in this case?

Comment: `Hex` is a representation, like decimal. `int` is a datatype, like `char`. The two concepts are entirely orthogonal; all 4 combinations make sense.

Answer (score 0):

An integer is an integer is an integer. It's still stored in binary, it's just the *presentation* (i.e. how you display it to the user) that you can change.

To display a character as a decimal number, just cast it to `int`:

```
char ch = 'a';
std::cout << static_cast<int>(ch) << '\n';
```

The above code will display the number `97` if your system uses ASCII (which it most likely does).

---

After clarifications, it seems you want the hexadecimal *digits* to become decimal *digits*.

If you have a *byte* (e.g. `char`) containing for example the value `0x11` (decimal `17`) then you simply have to take the first digit and multiply by ten, then add the second digit.

Like

```
char hex = 0x11;
int  dec = ((hex & 0xf0) >> 4) * 10 + (hex & 0x0f);
```

Note that this only works for hexadecimal digits below `a` (i.e. 0 to 9).

Comment: I tried int i = static_cast<int>(ifile.get()); but that didn't work.

Comment: What I meant is if we have 0x11 I don't want it to print 49 but 11 in decimal, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Napalidon What's wrong with `std::cout << std::hex << 0x11;`? [Works fine for me. Prints `11`.](http://ideone.com/dA4sUD)

Comment: @Napalidon Or do you mean you have the *string* `"0x11"` and wants to remove the `"0x"` part?

Comment: The thing is I don't want to print 11 but to convert hex 11 to dec 11 i.e. 0x11 = 49 but I want 11 in decimal so that would change hex to 0x0B

Comment: @Napalidon I'm not sure I follow, `0x11` is `17` decimal, and `0x31` is `49` decimal.

Comment: @Napalidon Also please see my updated answer. If that's still not what you want, then you have to update your question with more information, and maybe example input/output.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is: I am reading a hexdump that starts with 3131 but the file contains 11 as the first char and on next line 1A1B2... I was wondering why hexdump reads 31 and not 0xB does that have something to do with new line after 11?

Comment: @Napalidon You might want to check out an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Hex `0x31` (decimal 49, octal 61) is the ASCII value for the *character* `'1'`. So if you read the first two *characters* as text, you get the *characters* `'1'` and `'1'`, which you can put in a `std::string` to form the string `"11"`.

Comment: @Napalidon In the future, please include more information (like the contents (or hexdumps) of files, or input and expected and actual output) in the question. It will make it much easier to answer your questions.

Comment: Joachim there is this thread I really wanted to read, but I was busy and bookmarked it for when I had time. But when I came back to it, it got deleted and can only be viewed by someone with rating 10K or above. Can you check to see if you can view it and if you can could you send me a copy on my email? Sorry to ask but I really wanted to read it.  Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419969/c-dijkstra-implementation-with-map-container and my email is hamilton_24a@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string s="1F";
int x;   
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << s;
ss >> x; 
std::cout<<x<<std::endl; //This is base 10 value
std::cout<<static_cast<char> (x)<<std::endl; //This is ASCII equivalent
```

Comment: Does that change the hex 0x11 to decimal 11?

Comment: @Napalidon No it won't. Do you've a hex file for a micro-controller/processor ? (Intel Hex File) ?

Comment: No, I don't have that.